# What syntax deno --watch supports for file globs?

Tags: watch, deno

I am running

```
deno run -A --watch=./**/*.html,./**/*.js src/build.js
```

but changes to the globbed files are never triggering the build. Only changes from dependency graph of build.js are causing the build to happen. I tried using the quotes around the globs, or using only one or another without commas without success.

> ```
>     --watch[=<FILES>...]
>       Watch for file changes and restart process automatically.
>       Local files from entry point module graph are watched by default.
>       Additional paths might be watched by passing them as arguments to
>       this flag.
> ```

but I don’t seem to find what syntax the `<FILES>` should be.

I am using Deno 1.32.1 on macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deno expects the values in list arguments to use a comma as the separator, but lists produced by globbing use a space by default.

You can use shell features to modify the separator character in the list... or just use Deno. Here's an example using [brace expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146743/46524) that should work for your case:

```shell
deno run --watch=$(deno eval -p 'Deno.args.join(",")' ./**/*.{html,js}) src/build.js
```

Explanation of the watch argument:

```txt
$(                                                   ) # Run the command in a subshell
  deno eval -p                                         # Evaluate JavaScript from the command line
               'Deno.args.join(",")'                   # The code to evaluate (join input arguments on a comma)
                                     ./**/*.{html,js}  # The expanded glob list
```

---

So, for example, if you have a filesystem structure of `html` and `js` files like this:

```txt
% ls -1 ./**/*.{html,js}
./files/a.html
./files/a.js
./files/nested/b.html
./files/nested/b.js
./src/build.js
```

then the subshell command would produce a comma-separated list argument like this:

```txt
% deno eval -p 'Deno.args.join(",")' ./**/*.{html,js}
./files/a.html,./files/nested/b.html,./files/a.js,./files/nested/b.js,./src/build.js
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply! bummer, would be amazing if it accepted default globbing lists, if the param would be in quotes, for example.

I am not succeeding with HTML globs anyway: it seems like deno attempts to execute HTML as a JS module – "vendor/deno-1.32.1/bin/deno run --watch $(deno eval -p 'Deno.args.join(",")' ./src/**/*.html)  -A src/build.js 
Watcher Process started.
error: The module's source code could not be parsed: Expected ';', '}' or <eof> at file:///Users/misha/Source/balex.co.il/src/html/index.html:2:11

  <!doctype html>
            ~~~~
Watcher Process finished."

Comment: which is unexpected, as I am asking it to watch for changes, not to execute or parse these files.

Comment: Also, the sub shelling of `deno eval -p 'Deno.args.join(",")' ./**/*.{html,js}` breaks in Make for me, breaking at the second single quote: 
DENO_DIR=vendor/deno-1.32.1 vendor/deno-1.32.1/bin/deno  run --watch=' ./**/*.{html,js})  -A src/build.js
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903719/what-syntax-deno-watch-supports-for-file-globs/75904510?noredirect=1#comment133885867_75904510) @MishaReyzlin It sounds like that could be an issue with the `build.js` script, but we can't know unless you update the question with a [mre].

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903719/what-syntax-deno-watch-supports-for-file-globs/75904510#comment133885930_75904510) @MishaReyzlin Are you properly [escaping in your makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=makefile+escape)?

Comment: good point, thanks for the suggestion! here’s a minimal reproducible example with almost empty build.js https://gist.github.com/gryzzly/211c9c16a14cb9ca46d1a646335a0657 – it seems like deno is attempting to execute the html file instead of just watching it.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903719/what-syntax-deno-watch-supports-for-file-globs/75904510?noredirect=1#comment133965150_75904510) @MishaReyzlin In the code at that [link](https://gist.github.com/gryzzly/211c9c16a14cb9ca46d1a646335a0657) you are using the html file as the script argument. When providing a value to the `watch` argument, the equals sign must be used — example: `watch=file1,file2`. (Also, the [mre] belongs in the question details.)

Comment: argh, I’m blind! Thanks so much for catching!

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903719/what-syntax-deno-watch-supports-for-file-globs/75904510?noredirect=1#comment133976089_75904510) @MishaReyzlin Glad you got it fixed. I think the list-style args need [general re-engininering](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6553).

Comment: I went with printf in the end: `$(call deno) run --watch="$(printf "%s," ./src/**/*.{html,js})"  -A src/build.js` as I found it a bit easier to grasp from a quick scan. Agree on list args!